# Symfony 3.4 debug:translation call returning missing translations which are defined

Tags: symfony, twig, yaml, translation, symfony-3.4

When I run `debug:translation` in a Symfony 3.4 project I get a bunch of these:

```
bin/console debug:translation en CRMPiccoBundle --only-missing
 ----------- --------------- ------------------------------ -------------------------------------- 
  State       Domain          Id                            Message Preview (en)                  
 ----------- --------------- ------------------------------ -------------------------------------- 
   missing    homepage        login.signin.header.desktop   login.signin.header.desktop  
   missing    homepage        login.signin.header.mobile    login.signin.header.mobile
```

What confuses me is that the only template which is using these translations *is* correctly configured to access these translations:

```
{% extends "CRMPiccoBundle:Default:base.html.twig" %}
{% trans_default_domain "homepage" %}
{% set seodescription = 'page.description'|trans %}
{% set bodyclass = 'homepage login' %}
{% block title %}{{ 'page.title'|trans }}{% endblock %}

{% block flashes %}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<h1 class="d-none d-md-block">{{ 'login.signin.header.desktop'|trans }}</h1>
<h1 class="d-block d-md-none">{{ 'login.signin.header.mobile'|trans|raw }}</h1>
```

Why is `debug:translation` reporting these as "missing"?

`homepage.en.yml` looks like this:

```
login:
    signin:
        header:
            desktop: Sign-In
            mobile: Sign-In below
```

Comment: Apparently message preview use same value as key, so perhaps you defined for another language but it seems to be missing for `en` locale.

Comment: @Lounis Thanks for the comment. I only have one language defined in my application and i'm not sure what you mean about the message preview using the same value as key?

Comment: Key of translation e.g `login.signin.header.desktop` is same as its value `login.signin.header.desktop` usually it means that no value is defined for this translation, otherwise it would be the real sentance, but i see it's really defined in your yaml file. Perhaps it's because it's nested.

Comment: I tested it with Symfony 4.4.15 (env: dev, debug: true) and it worked well.

Comment: Does the translation work on the web app? Maybe there is problem with importing your translations?

Comment: @Lounis Nested translations are valid. So does this command not support nested translations? What was the full command you used to test this on your machine?

Comment: @UrmatZhenaliev Yes, all the translations work fine on the app. I have no errors. I’m just trying to cleanup unused translations as a housekeeping exercise. It seems this command isn’t much use.